# MongoDB vanishes attributes on save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hi im using MongoDB + Mongoose and some strange magic happens in my app.
Ive defined my Schema as

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' , required:true},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' , required:true},
  message: String
});
```

As I save my Document the new entry has ben saved and stored. It has a message and a ref on Profile in username but the user field is missing.

Same happens if I rename it to userId :/ Registered a pre save listener : already missing in my callback before save

There is no Error and I do not know how to handle this situation. Please help. Would call the a team but I can not afford

Edit :
Full Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' , required:true},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' , required:true},
    message: String
});

var autoPopulate = function(next) {
  this.populate('user');
  this.populate('username');
    next();
  };

  var autoReduce = function(next) {
    if(this.username){
          this.username = this.username._id;
    }
    if(this.user){
          this.user= this.user._id;
    }
    next();
  };

schema.
    pre('findOne', autoPopulate).
    pre('find', autoPopulate).
    pre('save', autoReduce);


    module.exports = mongoose.model('News',schema);
```

Request Body

```
{
        "message": "Hi",
        "username": {
            "_id": "5a736607bee0360014fb28e6",
            "name": "Juventus Florin"
        },
        "user": {
            "_id": "5a736607bee0360014fb28e6",
            "name": "Juventus Florin"
        }
    }
```

Code

```
  app.put("/api/news", function(request, response) {

            response.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var payload = request.body;
            new News(payload).save(function(err) {
                 if(err){
                        response.status(500).send({"message": "This is an error!", "error":err, "payload":payload});
                 }else{
                        response.status(200).send(payload);
                 }
             });
        });
```

After saving there is an new entry , looks like (username is populated)

```
{
        "message": "Hi",
        "username": {
            "_id": "5a736607bee0360014fb28e6",
            "name": "Juventus Florin"
        },
        "_id":"5a736607bee0360014fb278h"

    }
```

Comment: maybe there is an error you're not catching. when saving, save like this: `MySchema.save(function(err){console.log(err);});`

Comment: Have edit it @JohnnyHK

Comment: @rakan316 unfortunately not. there is no error but a new document becomes stored

Comment: I don't understand what the error is  you're describing.  `populate()` is not something you should be doing on save at all; it's something that's done when pulling a document out of the DB.

Comment: Dear @Paul , i expect the docunent to have user and username. But there is no user... It becomes vanished

Comment: Ok, but what your schema has defined is a reference to the user collection. What that means is that it will persist just the objectid associated with the user in the DB. You can call populate on a query to fetch it for display if you want or you can change your schema to have both the populatable attribute and a copy of the name.

Comment: @Paul  ... user and username is defined the same way , both got the same data, both got populatet the same way, nevertheless the user attribute does not apear in my document!

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
On 1 to 1 references there is no need to

```
this.user = this.user._id;
```

Only on 1 to Many references. Removed the pre save listener autoReduce and it works